# Memory errors batch inserting csv data into SQL Server using SQLAlchemy, pyodbc and MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, memory-management, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

As described in the title I am using SQLAlchemy and PYODBC in a python script to insert large csv files (up to 14GB) into a locally hosted SQL Server database.

I know that I cannot host a 14gb dataframe in memory so I am using the chunk feature in pandas to run batch inserts and have experimented with batch sizes as small as 100 rows which easily fits into memory.

I have a feeling the memory error is related to the SQL side of things. To minimize load processing I do not have any indexes on the tables I am inserting into (hash tables). No matter the batch size I am running out of memory at the same point in the loading process.

What am I overlooking? Should I be flushing the memory somehow? Or is SQL Server waiting to commit the transaction until the connection closes?

Here is my current code:

```
`import os
import glob
import traceback

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from tqdm import tqdm

# Replace the following variables with your database connection details
DB_USERNAME = '-----'
DB_PASSWORD = '-----'
DB_HOST = '------'
DB_NAME = '------'

DATA_DIRECTORY = "---------"
ERRORS_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(DATA_DIRECTORY, "errors")


def create_database_engine():
    engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}/{DB_NAME}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", fast_executemany=True )
    return engine

def batch_insert_to_database(engine, data, table, error_log_file):
    # Insert the data into the database in batches
    # The first batch will DROP ANY EXISTING TABLE IN THE DATABASE WITH THE SAME NAME
    try:
        data.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error_message = f"Error during batch insertion: {e}"
        print("error encountered")
        
        with open(error_log_file, 'a') as error_log:
            error_log.write(error_message + '\n')
            traceback.print_exc(file=error_log)

        return False
    return True

def load_table_data(csv, table, errors_directory):
    
    print(f"Beginning load for {table}")
    
    # Create a database engine
    engine = create_database_engine()

    # Create an empty errors DataFrame to store failed batches
    errors_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Batch size for insertion
    batch_size = 100

    # Initialize tqdm for progress tracking
    progress_bar = tqdm(total=0, desc="Processing")
    
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        truncate_command = text(f"TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[{table}]")
        connection.execute(truncate_command)

    error_report_file = os.path.join(errors_directory, f"errors_{table}.txt")
    # Read data from the CSV file in batches
    for batch_data in pd.read_csv(csv, chunksize=batch_size):
        # Try to insert the batch into the database
        success = batch_insert_to_database(engine, batch_data, table, error_report_file)

        # If the batch insertion fails, add the batch to the errors DataFrame
        if not success:
            errors_df = pd.concat([errors_df, batch_data])

        # Update the progress bar
        progress_bar.update(len(batch_data))

    # Close the progress bar
    progress_bar.close()


    error_data_file = os.path.join(errors_directory, f"errors_{table}.csv")
    # Save the errors DataFrame to a CSV file
    if not errors_df.empty:
        errors_df.to_csv(error_data_file, index=False)
        print(f"Errors saved to {error_data_file}")


def main():
    pattern = os.path.join(DATA_DIRECTORY, '**', '*.gz')
    gz_files = glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True)
    tables = [[file, file.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split(".")[0]] for file in gz_files]
    
    for table_data in tables:
        print(table_data)
        load_table_data(table_data[0], table_data[1], ERRORS_DIRECTORY)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 94, in main
    load_table_data(table_data[0], table_data[1], ERRORS_DIRECTORY)
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 66, in load_table_data
    success = batch_insert_to_database(engine, batch_data, table, error_report_file)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\main.py", line 29, in batch_insert_to_database
    data.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
  File "C:\...\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3008, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\pandas\io\sql.py", line 788, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1958, in to_sql
    total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1498, in insert_records
    return table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1059, in insert
    num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\pandas\io\sql.py", line 951, in _execute_insert
    result = conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1412, in execute
    return meth(
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 516, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1635, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1844, in _execute_context
    return self._exec_single_context(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1984, in _exec_single_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2342, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1934, in _exec_single_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 716, in do_executemany
    super().do_executemany(cursor, statement, parameters, context=context)
  File "C:\...\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 918, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
```

And the error message is simply "MemoryError".

Further investigation revealed it is a specific file that is causing the error even if I don't load prior ones. I am starting to think it might be a bad error message. Thank you for all the suggestions. I don't see how there could be a memory error retrieving 100 rows with 6 columns from a csv. I will post if/when I find it.

Comment: Can you append the actual error you're getting to your question? And check the autocommit setting of your connection

Comment: Is there a simple way to de-identify the stack-trace (directory references)?

Comment: The actual error message I am receiving outside of the stack trace is "MemoryError".

Comment: When you specify `chunksize` doesn't `pd.read_csv` return a `TextFileReader` instead of a dataframe?

Comment: How long does it last before memory error?  Does some data make it into the db?

Comment: Maybe the file has wrong line endings so dataframe ingests whole file as one long blob

Comment: You already have the data in csv files so why not just use the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) to upload them directly?

Comment: The bcp utility was throwing unclear error messages, of my 24 tables I was able to use bcp for 23 of them. Wound up using this python script as is for the last one and it didn't throw the memory error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot of sqlserver but maybe try this to see if the entire import is trying to pile up in a single transaction, there might be a better way but this would be informative, (this would commit every batch):

```py
def batch_insert_to_database(engine, data, table, error_log_file):
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        data.to_sql(table, con=conn, index=False, if_exists='append')
    return True
```